# Java / Hibernate - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, excel, hibernate, apache-poi

I'm working on a program that reads specified columns of an XLS file and saves this data to a MySQL database (InnoDB engine, utf8-default collation).

I implemented a function to check whether the file has changed and if so, the program should only write the differences to the database. I am using **Hibernate (with use of the function `session.saveOrUpdate()`)** for mapping and **Apache POI** for the file handling.

The first time I run this program against an empty database, everything runs pretty well so far.

**ISSUE:**
I get the **`MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2014-09-10 16:09:28' for key 'PRIMARY'`** when there are entries already present in the database (and when I try to feed the program with **the exact same XLS file** as on the run before, which logically means it should not update or save anything).

To determine whether the data from the database and the data from the XLS file are equal, I use the following code, which fetches all entries from the database into a list of my domain objects (List list) and sorts & compares that to the list of domain objects I get from the XLS file:

```
public void retrieveFromDB() {
        try {
            DatabaseManager _dbManager = new DatabaseManager(SessionFactoryUtil.SYSTEM_ID_PARAMETER);
            _dbManager.beginTransaction();
            setBackupValuesList(_dbManager.getDomainObject());
            System.out.println("SIZE OF LIST 1: " + getBackupValuesList().size());
            _dbManager.commitTransaction();
            _dbManager.endTransaction();
            log.info("RETRIEVED DATA FROM DATABASE!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.fatal("UNABLE TO OPEN DB CONNECTION OR COMMITING TRANSACTION!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public DomainObject determineLastFromDB(List<DomainObject> backupValuesList) {
        DomainObject gdhElement = null;
        if (backupValuesList.size() == 0) {
            log.info("NO OBJECTS IN DATABASE!");
        }
        else {
            Iterator<DomainObject > itr = backupValuesList.iterator();
            gdhElement = itr.next();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                gdhElement = itr.next();
            }
        }
        return gdhElement;
    }

public List<DomainObject> removeOldDataFromXLS(DomainObject gdhElement) {
                if (backupValuesList.size() == 0 || gdhElement.equals(null)) {
                    log.info("NO OBJECTS IN DATABASE! COPYING ALL DATA!");
                }

                else if (backupValuesList.size() != 0 || !(gdhElement.equals(null))) {
                    Iterator<DomainObject> iter = xlsValuesList.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        DomainObjectelement = iter.next();
                        // remove all elements that are older than the latest element
                        // date in the database
                        if ((element.getDate().before(gdhElement.getDate()))) {
                            iter.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return xlsValuesList;
            }
```

My hibernate_localhost.cfg.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="connection.username"> removed </property>
        <property name="connection.password"> removed </property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- this will show us all sql statements -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>


        <!-- Pooling settings -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">0</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">30</property>
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">600</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property>

        <!-- mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="path/to/DomainObject.hbm.xml"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Hibernate mapping file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 5, 2014 6:01:25 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="path.to.DomainObjectClass" table="tablename">
        <id name="date" type="java.sql.Date">
            <column name="date" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="value" type="double">
            <column name="value" />
        </property>
        <property name="whenModified" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="whenModified" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What I don't get is the following:

**Date (primary key) of latest entry in database:** 2014-09-09
**Date of latest entry in XLS file:** 2014-09-09
**Date shown in the Exception as duplicate entry:** 2014-09-10 16:09:28

It always shows the **current date/time** in the Exception (not the date from the XLS entry), which I am definitely NOT trying to save to the database.

I tried a lot of debugging but I don't see the solution while being totally confused! Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace of the error? Also the code to save an entity to db?

Comment: I finally found out that it wasn't a problem of my program logic. The MySQL column I was saving data to is of type "TIMESTAMP", and when the table was created, the default value of that column was set to "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". Thank you anyway!